# How to link a Watson service to a folder in IBM Cloud, the way I can use it on AJAX JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have the following code in JQuery:

```
// Using the core $.ajax() method
$.ajax({
                 
    // The URL for the request
    url: "XXX",
                 
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8', 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + btoa("apikey:"+"XXX") //The API-KEY
    },
```

This code works on cloud IBM but the problem it's that **the api-key it's visible** for the client.
Is there a way to link the *url* to a folder in my cloud server the way I can put in the url request, for example *'/tone-analyzer'* and **without the api-key**? Am I not in the intern side of my cloud? Why I can't directly call to *Tone Analyzer* service? Have I to configure some api gateway?
Sorry I'm a bit new to the cloud concepts. Any help will be welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before launching your product in production, you should use a back-end service to obscure your API key. Any API key in the browser can easily be inspected and re-used, running up your hosting bills.

More information: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/private-api-keys/

Comment: Thank you, I realized that I must use a back-end service in Node.js. I have added some code to my app.js and now works secured.